# Проверка вводимых данных на корректность на Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, исключения, условия, данные

Задача состоит в следующем: пишу кода на Python 3.10. Необходимо, чтобы пользователь ввёл с клавиатуру пару значений через пробел таким образом, чтобы:

1. Первое значение - буква "R" или "L"
2. Второе значение - целое число

Необходимо осуществить проверку на корректность ввода, т.е. на тип данных и их порядок. Возможно ли это сделать без нагромождения условных конструкций? (Например, через try-except с подхватом ValueError)? Сижу уже третий день и никак не могу понять, как сделать) Основная проблема в том, чтобы проверить именно второе значение, т.к. int() выполняет преобразование дробных чисел к целым... Подскажите, дураку, как эту проблему можно решить?

Comment: Ну через int и проверяйте. Если в строке не целое число, то упадет с ошибкой ValueError, его и отлавливайте через try-except.

Comment: если данные вводит пользователь, то и первое и второе значения у вас будут строками. int строку с вещественным числом выплюнет в ошибку.

Comment: @insolor, при использовании int(<имя_переменной>) выполняется округление, и именно в этом загвоздка....

Comment: @VannKult пользователь у вас вводит через input, а input возвращает строку. `int("12.3")` вызовет ValueError, а не округление. Загвоздки нет, загвоздка только в вашей голове)

Answer (score 0):

У меня такой вариант:

```py
a = input().split()
try:
    print( "YES" if a[0] in ['R', 'L'] and int( a[1] ) else "NO" )
except:
    print( "Exception" )
```

выведет `YES`, если Ваше условие верно, и `NO` в противном случае, а если будет ошибка, выведет `Exception`
Ответ на скорую руку, если будут вопросы обращайтесь.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать [регулярные выражения](https://habr.com/ru/post/349860/) (Regular expression):

```
import re


r = re.compile(r'[LR] \d+')

if r.match(s):
    ...


print(r.match('L '))         # None
print(r.match('L 150'))      # Match object
print(r.match('R 5465'))     # Match object
print(r.match('R5465'))      # None
print(r.match('R54 65'))     # None
print(r.match('R'))          # None
print(r.match('RL 455465'))  # None
print(r.match(' 455465'))    # None
print(r.match('A 455465'))   # None
```

Если ещё нужно достать значения, тогда нужно использовать группы (Группирующие скобки в регулярных выражениях)